# Creating a core data model

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I want to create a core data model. I have a pameter of type

> CFUUIDRef

How will I represent this object in coredata model? I can see only basic types in cdatamodelling screen.

How can I do this with coredata?

Answer (score 0):

You would have to use a string or binary data type in your model and `NSManagedObject` subclass. Then use the CFUUID methods `CFUUIDGetUUIDBytes` and `CFUUIDCreateFromUUIDBytes` whenever you need to set / retrieve the value.